# Iterating nd array Python: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python-3.x

I have the follow nd array and array centroids

```
ndArr = np.array([
                  [24, 6.2],
                  [2, 2.4],
                  [41, 5.1],
                  [12, 4.4]
])

centroids = np.array([0, 1], dtype = float)
```

And I want my function to iterate it like so:

```
def performDistanceToCentroid(data, centroids):

  for i in centroids:
    for j in ndArr:
      print(j[0])
```

but I keep getting the error:

`IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

when I call:

```
performDistanceToCentroid(ndArr, centroids)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code that you run? I don't see any errors upon running this.

Comment: that's it. that's the whole code. Im running it in collab @0dminnimda

Comment: I can guess that the issue is that `ndArr` is changed to some other value between declaring it and running `performDistanceToCentroid`, so try to reload and run only this code again. And also use the `data` inside of the `performDistanceToCentroid` and not `ndArr`